# timing how long an element has been in a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What would be the easiest way to track how long an element has been part of a list? For instance, I would like to pop an element from a list after it has been added for 2 minutes.

Would I have to create two lists, one holding the actual element and the other the time that element was added to the list? Then checking the "time" list in order to know when it has reached two minutes?

I have a feeling theres a much simpler and efficient method to do this but I cannot think of it at the moment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have the minimum amount of code to write, you can have a look at the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class, which implements an expiration policy.

Using the [CacheItemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx) you can even have a callback method executed when the item is removed after expiration.

Comment: Will have a look at it now :) Sounds like its exactly what I am looking for, especially with the callback!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than storing the elements in the lists directly, you could use a wrapper class which included the element and its storage time, then store instances of the wrapper class instead.

You would probably want to use a queue rather than a list; you will be removing items from the front a lot, which is far more efficient with a queue than with a list.

How often you check the queue is something you'd need to decide on. You could possibly use a separate thread to check every so often, in which case you'd probably want to use a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

Comment: that was what I was thinking currently, thought there would be a way to do it without the wrapper class but I guess your suggestion does the job :)